# Recognizing Variable from another function

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, global

I am making a game for RockPaperScissors. I have a function that generates the computers choice, then have a function that reacts to the clicking of a button, then a function for playing the game combining both functions.

I have tried accessing it through the functions, and have been doing research but cant find a way to get the variable to make its way to the last function. Do I have to combine all of them to a single function in order to get the variable.

```
/*This function generates the computer's choice and then presents a rock image, removing it after 2 seconds.*/
function computerChoice() {
  let compChoice = Math.random();
  if (compChoice < 0.33) {
    compChoice = "rock";
    cpuChoice.classList.add(rockImage, rockImage2);
    setTimeout(function () {
      cpuChoice.classList.remove(rockImage, rockImage2);
    }, 2000);
  } else if (compChoice < 0.66 && compChoice > 0.33) {
    compChoice = "paper";
    cpuChoice.classList.add(paperImage, paperImage2);
    setTimeout(function () {
      cpuChoice.classList.remove(paperImage, paperImage2);
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    compChoice = "scissors";
    cpuChoice.classList.add(scissorImage, scissorImage2);
    setTimeout(function () {
      cpuChoice.classList.remove(scissorImage, scissorImage2);
    }, 2000);
  }
}

/*Here is the function thats having issues, I cant seem to get the gameResults innerHTML to change since it wont gather the compChoice.*/
function playGame(humanChoice, compChoice) {
  if (humanChoice === compChoice) {
    gameResults.innerHTML = "tie";

  } else if (humanChoice === "rock" && compChoice === "scissor") {
    gameResults.innerHTML = "You won!";
  } else if (humanChoice === "rock" && compChoice === "paper") {
    gameResults.innerHTML = "The computer won!";
  } else if (humanChoice === "paper" && compChoice === "rock") {
    gameResults.innerHTML = "You won!";
  } else if (humanChoice === "paper" && compChoice === "scissor") {
    gameResults.innerHTML = "The computer won!";
  } else if (humanChoice === "scissor" && compChoice === "rock") {
    gameResults.innerHTML = "The computer won!";
  } else if (humanChoice === "scissor" && compChoice === "paper") {
    gameResults.innerHTML = "You won!";
  } else {
    gameResults.innerHTML = "Not Possible";
  }
}

/*This function generates the human's choice from a click and then presents an image of the choice, removing it after 2 seconds. Then calls for computerChoice(), and attempts to call the playGame functions.*/
allButtons.forEach(function (e) {
  e.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const choice = e.dataset.play;
    if (choice === "rock") {
      humanChoice = "rock";
      computerChoice();
      yourChoice.classList.add(rockImage, rockImage2);
      setTimeout(function () {
        yourChoice.classList.remove(rockImage, rockImage2);
      }, 2000);
      playGame(humanChoice, compChoice);
    } else if (choice === "paper") {
      humanChoice = "paper";
      computerChoice();
      yourChoice.classList.add(paperImage, paperImage2);
      setTimeout(function () {
        yourChoice.classList.remove(paperImage, paperImage2);
      }, 2000);
      playGame(humanChoice, compChoice);
    } else if (choice === "scissors") {
      humanChoice = "scissors";
      computerChoice();
      yourChoice.classList.add(scissorImage, scissorImage2);
      setTimeout(function () {
        yourChoice.classList.remove(scissorImage, scissorImage2);
      }, 2000);
      playGame(humanChoice, compChoice);
    }
  });
});
```

I am expecting the gameResults.innerHTML to change, but it wont because it wont gather the CompChoice's variable to compare to the HumanChoices.

Comment: You define varible compChoice inside function so it is not avaible out that function scope. You can set  computerChoice function to return compChoice, and inside yur event for all buttons you can defince that choice, eg var compChoice = computerChoice(), then do your logic with that. You can also define it as global variable ( outside you function ), and just update it inside your function like this  compChoice = Math.random(); and every time you call your function it will update and be avaible in your code.

Comment: Also next time please click the `[<>]` snippet editor to create a [mcve]